# Как работать с length в массиве?

Tags: массивы, typescript

Есть массив printingEditions: PrintingEdition[];
Хочу найти его длину пишу

```
this.printingEditions.length()
```

А оно ругается

```
  Type 'Number' has no call signatures.
```

Подскажите как узнать длину массива?

Answer (score 0):

Просто: `this.printingEditions.length`. [Это свойство, не метод.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

Comment: Если так писать, то получаю ошибку ```Cannot read property 'length' of null``` в консоль

Comment: @Dmitriy значит там, где вы осуществляете доступ к свойству length значение `this.printingEditions` не определено

Comment: @ nörbörnën понял

Comment: @Dmitriy, если помог, то не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)